# How would I create a dent on a car from a falling object? Details in body message

Tags: physics, soft-body

I'm trying to create the effect of dents being created on a vehicle (or any simple mesh to be honest) by dropping an object onto it. That's not quite my end goal, I'm really just trying to find out how to leave dented impressions on a mesh.

I was told this could be accomplished through giving the mesh (a low poly car in this case) softbody physics but none of my tinkering seems to be working. The ball either bounces off harmlessly or the car "sinks into the floor" like in the pictures I'm sharing.

I've been messing around with this for hours and in various combinations, so I must be missing something. I just want to be able to dent the mesh as if it were a sturdy plastic. Any help / insight would be greatly appreciated.

[image: Text]
Showing off the car settings a bit.

[image: Text]
More car settings. Plus showing what happens mid-simulation.

[image: Text]
And then the plane settings.

Again, thank you for your time and consideration.

Answer (score 1):

If you go in the object data properties , the triangle with 3 dots , you'll find a setting known as shape key , so you can create 2 shape keys , one will be the Undented shape and another will be the dented shape , you can sculpt or manually move vertices o make the dented shape and then you can keyframe the value below it to the frame when your object descends.

Comment: That sounds very helpful! I'm new to this site so I'm sorry if I'm not replying to your Answer properly, but I really appreciate your time. I'll spend some time trying to apply your Answer, however I'm not sure where Object Data Properties are at. I'll continue looking for it, but I really appreciate your response, thank you.

Comment: no problem!! welcome to the comunity